# How to speed up spark sql filter queries if the where clause is already fixed?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my case, the data resides in spark tables which are created by calling createOrReplaceTempView API on a dataframe. Once the table is created, several queries are going to run on top of the table. Most of the time, the where query is going to be based on a particular column. The concerned columns' name is already known. I would like to know if some sort of optimizations can be done to improve the performance of the filter query.
I tried exploring the approach of indexing but it turns out spark does not support indexing a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the SPARK UI to see where most of your time is being consumed?  Is it really the query where most of the time is spent?  Usually reading the data from disk is where most of the time is spent.  Learn to read the SPARK UI and find where the real bottleneck is.  The SQL tab is a really great way to start figuring things out.

Here's some tricks to run faster in spark that apply to most jobs:

**Can you reframe the problem?**  Was the data you are using in a format that helps you solve the query?  Can you change how it's written to change the problem?  (Could you start "pre-chewing" the data before you even query it to have it stored in the best format to help you solve the issue you want to solve?)  Most performance gains come from changing the parameters of the problem to make them easier/faster to solve.

**What format (is the incoming data) you are
storing the data in?**  Are you using Parquet/Orc? They have a great payoff disk space/compression that are worth using.  They also can enable file level filter to *speed read*.  Is their transformation work that you can push upstream to help make the query do less work?  Can you be writing the data via a partition schema that would aid lookups?

**How many files is your input?** Can you consolidate files to maximize read throughput.  Reading/listing a lot of small files as input slows down the processing of data.

If the tempView query is of similar size every time you could look at tweaking the partition count so that files are smaller but approximately the size of your HDFS block size.  (Assuming you are using hdfs).  HDFS you have to read an entire block weather you use all the data or not.  Try and fit this to some multiple of your executors so that you are finishing together and not straggling. This is hard to get perfect but you can make decent strides to find a good ratio.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to optimize filter conditions with spark. spark already is smart enough to optimize its conditions post where query to fetch minimum rows first. The best I guess you can do is by persisting your  TempView if querying the same view again and again.